# Multiple Dependency Module in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, Is it possible to add more than one dependency module in AngularJS ?

**code:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['dependency1','dependency2']);
```

**`I even tried this but no luck`**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['dependency1'],['dependency2']);
```

Any help will be highly appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Your first attempt will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['dependency1','dependency2']);
```

is the way to add dependencies.

Advice : You should check your console and see why your code doesn't work.
Let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to add multiple module dependencies.

```
angular.module("name", ["dependencyA", "dependencyB"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in your first example with

```
angular.module('myApp',['dependency1','dependency2']);
```

Make sure that the spelling is correct with these dependencies, such that if you use ngRoute and ngResource that it looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ngResource']);
```

You will also get an error in the console if you do not add the js to your html page, so be sure to look out for that.